# Is there any way to convert string [which is an object some class] to object of some class?

Tags: java, collections

```
private static void method() {
List<HashMap<Integer, String>> repeating = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  HashMap<Integer, String> group = new HashMap<>();
  group.put(958, "958value-" + i);
  group.put(959, "959value-" + i);
  group.put(960, "960value-" + i);
  repeating.add(group);
}

/*Is there any way to change listObj to again List object*/
String listObj = repeating.toString();}
```

I will be getting string of List object which I want to convert to List object. Is there any way to convert that string to List?

Comment: in most cases, no, but you might be able to map it to that other type

Comment: If you know how your list is structured - yes. But you would've to parse on your own, based on this structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization instead of toString.
Take a look at Gson / Jackson.
That libraries allow convert object to string and parse string to object back.

Gson for example allows you to transform any object to a JSON and then back to the object this way:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
// Populate the list
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonifiedList = gson.toJson(list1);
```

Then do what you need with the String form of the list and retrieve it:

```
List<String> list2 = gson.fromJson(jsonifiedList, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType());
```

If your list contains more complex objects, you may need to add a `JsonSerializer` to your `Gson` object so it knows how to create and parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case the answer is no. In some cases the `toString` method for a class generates a string that is compatible with a corresponding parse method or constructor in the class. Then you can convert back. Normally information is lost when an object is converted into a string format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible although i didn't get everything from you question

Create a List of the object List

then iterate your map with

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : yourmap.entrySet()) {
          new List<YourObject> lst;
          lst.add(new Object(entry.getkey, entry.getvalue));
```

but i suggest you dont use and map i dont see why you need it prefer a list an arraylist if you want to iterate on it